# ros serial Arduino, Propeller

Tags: ros, arduino, rosseral-arduino, rosserial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was hoping to get ROS-serial and the Arduino working together -  but I keep getting stuck with the librxtx.  There always seems to be a version mismatch between the architecture and the module.

Also, has anyone got ROS serial working with the parallax propeller chip -  it seems to be a much more capable controller than the Arduino

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10428/ros-serial-arduino,-propeller/) by [DrBot](https://answers.ros.org/users/765/drbot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 147 on 2011-06-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have solved lib errors these issues by loading a new ros (diamondback,  and new libboost.

Now I am getting a traceback import error on serial_node.py  no module rosserial_msgs.msg

thanks.

---

Originally posted by [DrBot](https://answers.ros.org/users/765/drbot/) with karma: 147 on 2011-07-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0